# Mathematical programming puzzles

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded

This is a solution I wrote for a programming puzzle which I believe and I'm sure is correct, but for two of their test cases the online judge gives me 'Time Limit Exceeded' only by a few 100ms! I've tried a lot to knock those few ms out, but no luck.

For a time limit of 3s I've submitted solutions which ran in 3.13127s, 3.2901s, 3.02861s. (personally, I find it annoying how a fraction of sec is keeping my solution from getting accepted)

Here's so far what I've paid attention to:

1. I've minimized the `stdin`, `stdout` operations by storing the input & output appropriately.
2. I've done proper memoization for `Divisors` and `CPStrings` class.
3. As mod operator is said to be expensive so I've performed only when necessary etc.
4. The function `NChooseK_Sum` sums up the Binomial coefficients of \$N\$ up to \$K\$, using Pascal's triangle approach \$O(N^2)\$. I wrote a \$O(KlogK)\$ solution but surprisingly it only went on to increase the run time on submission! (I've attached both functions)
   As far as logic of solution is concerned I'm sure this is pretty much it. It is a simple dynamic programming problem, requires divisors and some hamming distance calculations.

Help me review this code and point out the expensive lines/ideas in it. I think using `map<int, vector<int> >` could be expensive but I can't find any easier alternative of it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 1000000007
long long int NChooseK_Sum(int N, int K){
    vector<long long int> prevV, V;
    prevV.push_back(1);     prevV.push_back(1);
    for(int i=2;i<=N;++i){
        V.push_back(1);
        for(int j=0;j<(i-1);++j){
            long long int val = prevV[j] + prevV[j+1];
            if(val > MAX)
                val %= MAX;
            V.push_back(val);
        }
        V.push_back(1);
        prevV = V;
        V.clear();
    }
    long long int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=K;++i){
        res+=prevV[i];
        if(res >= MAX)
            res %= MAX;
    }
    return res;
}
class Divisors{
    map<int, vector<int> >M;
    public:
    vector<int> GetDivisors(int N){
        map<int, vector<int> >::iterator mit = M.find(N);
        if(mit != M.end())
            return mit->second;
        else{
            vector<int> V;
            int L = sqrt(N)+1;
            for(int i=1;i<L;++i)
                if( !(N%i) ){
                    V.push_back(i);
                    if(i != N/i)
                        V.push_back(N/i);
                }
            sort(V.begin(), V.end());
            M.insert(pair<int, vector<int> > (N, V) );
            return V;
        }
    }
};

class CPStrings{
    long long int cache[1000][1000];
    public:
    CPStrings(){
        memset(cache, -1, sizeof(long long int)*1000*1000);
    }
    long long int CountPeriodicStrings(vector<string> &V, int edits_left, int idx){
        if(idx == -1 && edits_left >=0)
            return 1;
        if(edits_left<0)
            return 0;
        if(cache[edits_left][idx] != -1)
            return cache[edits_left][idx];
        long long int ret = 0;
        char alphabet[2] = {'0','1'};
        for(int ch = 0; ch<2; ++ch){
            int edits_used = 0;
            vector<string>::iterator sit;
            for(sit=V.begin(); sit!=V.end(); ++sit)
                if((*sit)[idx] != alphabet[ch])
                    ++edits_used;
            ret += CountPeriodicStrings(V, edits_left-edits_used, idx-1);
        }
        if(ret >= MAX)
            ret %= MAX;
        cache[edits_left][idx] = ret;
        return ret;
    }
};
void BreakString(const string &s, int size, vector<string> &Res){
    int len = s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len; i+=size)
        Res.push_back(s.substr(i, size));
}
class Problem{
    int _T;
    int *_N, *_K;
    map<int, string> Probs;
    public:
    Problem(){
        cin >> _T;
        _N = new int[_T];
        _K = new int[_T];
    }
    ~Problem(){
        delete []_N;
        delete []_K;
    }
    void ReadProblem(){
        for(int i=0;i<_T;++i){
            cin >> _N[i] >> _K[i];
            string s;
            cin >> s;
            Probs.insert(pair<int, string>(i, s) );
        }
        return;
    }
    void Solve(vector<long long int> &Result){
        Divisors D;
        for(int t=0; t<_T; ++t){
            int N=_N[t], K=_K[t];
            map<int, string>::iterator mit = Probs.find(t);
            string s = mit->second;
            long long int totalStrings = 0;
            //Total possible stringsCount = NC0+NC1+NC2+...+NCK
            totalStrings = NChooseK_Sum(N, K);
            //Periodic strings' period  will be of length (p=) 1,2,...(divisors of L)
            vector<int> divisors = D.GetDivisors(N);
            long long int periodicStringCount = 0;
            map<int, long long int> M; // Map M contains the divisor(d): #periodicstrings with period =d.
            for(int i=0; i<divisors.size()-1; ++i){//For all Periods calculate the possible periodic strings that could be formed...
                CPStrings CPS;
                int divisor = divisors[i];
                vector<string> subStrings;
                BreakString(s, divisor, subStrings);
                long long int periodicStringCount_withRep = CPS.CountPeriodicStrings(subStrings ,K, divisor-1);
                if(periodicStringCount_withRep){
                    vector<int> divs = D.GetDivisors(divisor);
                    for(vector<int>::iterator vit=divs.begin();vit!=divs.end()-1; ++vit){//Remove the repetaed patterns formed by the divisors of current Period.
                        map<int, long long int>::iterator mit = M.find(*vit);
                        if(mit != M.end())
                            periodicStringCount_withRep -= mit->second;
                    }
                }
                while(periodicStringCount_withRep < 0)
                    periodicStringCount_withRep += MAX;
                M.insert(pair<int, long long int>(divisor, periodicStringCount_withRep));
                periodicStringCount += periodicStringCount_withRep;
            }
            if(periodicStringCount >= MAX)
                periodicStringCount %= MAX;
            long long int result = totalStrings - periodicStringCount;
            while(result < 0)
                result += MAX;
            Result.push_back(result);
        }
        return;
    }
};
int main(){
    Problem P;
    P.ReadProblem();
    vector<long long int> Result;
    P.Solve(Result);
    for(int i=0;i<Result.size(); ++i)
        cout << Result[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
#define 1000000007 MAX
void ExtendedEucledian(long long int a, long long int b, long long int& gcd, long long int& x, long long int& y){
        x=0, y=1;
        long long int u=1, v=0, m, n, q, r;
        gcd = b;
        while (a!=0) {
                q=gcd/a; r=gcd%a;
                m=x-u*q; n=y-v*q;
                gcd=a; a=r; x=u; y=v; u=m; v=n;
        }
}
long long int NChooseK_Sum1(int N, int K){
        long long int val = 1, sum = 1;
        for(int k=0;k<K;++k){
                long long int gcd, moduloInverse, y;
                ExtendedEucledian(k+1, MAX, gcd, moduloInverse, y);
                if(moduloInverse<0)
                        moduloInverse += MAX;
                val = val * (N-k);
                if(val >= MAX)
                        val %= MAX;
                val *= moduloInverse;
                if(val >= MAX)
                        val %= MAX;
                sum += val;
                if(sum >= MAX){
                        sum %= MAX;
                }
        }
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: Leave cin and cout. Instead use read and write.

Comment: Whitespace is your friend use it to make the code readable. Source code is meant for humans to read. you should try and make it nice to read this is overly dense.

Comment: A link (or preferably) a description of the problem may help. When speed is involved it is usually an incorrect algorithm that is being used ie O(n^2) rather than O(n) solution. I see several double nested loops.

Comment: Simple help: 1) Use reserve() on vectors before putting stuff in them. 2) When you create a vector then put it into a map this is expensive. Put an empty vector into the map then swap it with the vector you have calculated. 3) Returning a vector is expensive return by const reference to avoid the copy.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Thanks, I'll keep that in mind while using vectors inside a map and that reserve() feature too.

Comment: @LokiAstari I thought the spirit of the day(I did at least hear it like that several times on Going-Native) is to return by value because it will automatically be moved?

Comment: @bamboon: Yes return by value can be optimized by using the move constructor if available is what the compiler will try and do. **BUT** the compiler has to recognize that this is a valid optimization and it can fail this recognition. Also if you use my point (2) and optimization map creation by swapping into the map first then you can't use the move constructor as the object is part of the map so you need to return a reference to the member inside the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Some low-hanging fruit in the NChooseK_Sum code:

   Initialize two vectors up-front to a full allocation of N elements to avoid resizing overhead.

   Don't call `clear` -- instead, just use `V[0] = 1;` `V[j] = ...;` `V[i] = 1;` instead of `V.push_back`.

   Also, you could avoid the vector-to-vector copying by defining V and prevV as pointers  to vectors and swapping the two pointers at the bottom of the loop. (The vectors could STILL be stack-based if you care, just give them other names like vecA and vecB and take their addresses to set the pointers.
2. Some low-hanging fruit in the CountPeriodicStrings code:

   Instead of testing `(edits_left<0)` (effectively twice!?) inside *every* call,
   save function call overhead by skipping the *recursive call* in the equivalent case `(edits_left<edits_used)`.

   Since V doesn't change for the duration of a the recursive call and needn't change
   over the lifetime of the CPStrings object, save some argument passing by making it a data member.

   You could also save iterator overhead by pulling the vector iterator loop out of the 
   `for(int ch...` loop so it only gets called once. That requires calculating two different `edits_used` values in parallel, one per {'0','1'}. I'd probably eliminate the `for(int ch...` loop for edits_used calculation purposes, especially since '0' and '1' are mutually exclusive, and save the looping for the recursive call like this:

   ```
   long long int ret = 0;
   int edits_used[] = {0,0};
   for(vector<string>::iterator sit=V.begin(); sit!=V.end(); ++sit) {
       switch ((*sit)[idx]) {
       case '0':
           ++(edits_used[0]);
           break;
       case '1':
           ++(edits_used[1]);
           break;
       default:
           break;
       }
   }
   for(int ch = 0; ch<2; ++ch)
       if(edits_left>=edits_used[ch])
           ret += CountPeriodicStrings(V, edits_left-edits_used[ch], idx-1);
   ```
3. There are a number of for loops over vectors that use `size()` and integer indexing rather than iterators. I'm not sure how this effects performance, but it's not as readable.

It's hard to tell without profiling whether these changes are addressing actual pain points, but they're what jumped out. They *may* give the slight edge you are seeking.

Comment: Thank you, for your time and useful suggestions. I worked on two of your suggestions which helped me restict my solution within the time limit. 
1. In NChooseK_Sum, that overhead of copying of vector after every loop. In fact I rewrote the function using single pointer to array only. 
2. Saving that last needless call to the recursive function of CPStrings. Also, refactoring the recursive code of  CountPeriodicStrings and bringing that iterator out.